# How does the subtype information gets preserved when collection type is a parent type?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference, type-erasure

How,in the following examples, do the type of individual elements get preserved without being converted to the supertype used as type parameter to collection?

```
scala> trait T
defined trait T

scala> case class CC1(f: Int) extends T
defined class CC1

scala> case class CC2(f: String) extends T
defined class CC2

scala> val lt: List[T] = List(CC1(1),CC2("a"))
lt: List[T] = List(CC1(1), CC2(a))

scala> lt.collect {case e: CC1 => e.f}
res11: List[Int] = List(1)
```

or better still

```
scala> List[Any](1,"a").collect {case e: Int => e}
res12: List[Int] = List(1)
```

This is the compile time behavior and so cannot be attributed to erasure in runtime jvm.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching happens at runtime, not at compile-time. All type information was lost.
`case foo: Foo` is not a type match *(even if it called like that)* but is a class match *(it is almost the same as `foo.isInstanceOf[Foo]`)*.

You can see that if you try to match with something that lost type information due to erasure, for example:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), List("a", "b", "c")).foreach {
  case _: List[Int] => println("Is a List of Ints")
  case _: List[String] => println("Is a List of String")
}
```

You will see that it prints: *"Is a List of Ints"* twice.

---

That is the reason why that kind of pattern matching is discouraged, if you need to know which subclasses you have, you have a design error.

Comment: thanks for the example. Yes, I do realize what that happens..

Comment: "Pattern matching happens at runtime, not at compile-time. All type information was lost.
case foo: Foo is not a type match (even if it called like that) but is a class match (it is almost the same as foo.isInstanceOf[Foo])"

couple of questions on your comment above:

1. Isn't a class and/or trait considered a type in scala
2. the type inference does work in compile time, that is if I write something like 

val str: String = lt.collect {case e: CC1 => e.f} 

it will complain that right side returns List[Int]

Comment: @RupamBhattacharjee 1) Actually not, a **class** or a **trait** imply a **type** of the same name; however, they are still [different things](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html). - 2) I never said that type inference wasn't in compile-time, what I said is that when the pattern match is executed is in runtime as such at execution time there are not types. The compiler ensures that if it compiled then it is typesafe _(most of the time)_, but you can force it to compile unsafe code by direct or indirect use of `asInstanceOf` _(class matches are an indirect use)_